# Amazon MWS TrackingEvents Code translation

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm using Amazon MWS to track multi-channel orders on my website with the GetPackageTrackingDetails() function.

Does Amazon provide something to get a translated sentence for the EventCode in the response ?

Thanks